# Umbrella term for arrays and lists

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, terminology

Is there a good umbrella term for these two data structures?
Sometimes the only thing I care about is that the structure is one-dimensional, ordered, allows duplicates etc., but it is really important that I'm not too specific.
I was thinking about vector, but that seems to be specifically a structure 
that's indexed in constant time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you're talking about is **data structure**.

Each of those (array, list, etc.) are types of data structures. A good resource for the categorization is the [Dictionary of Algorithms and Data Structures](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads//). But "data structures" is an umbrella term covers a lot more than just one-dimensional, ordered, allows duplicates, etc. Data structures just references a way of organizing data so that it can be efficiently accessed and used.

To get more specific, referencing *only* arrays, vectors, lists, etc. you'd be best to either use their actual name, or use "array-like data structure" and specify what uniquely identifies that data structure. i.e. *A vector is an array-like data structure with a dynamically allocated size.*

Comment: Well, I don't want trees or tables so "data structure" doesn't work. But I guess "array-like" does the job even though i doubt people will get what I mean the first time.